# troubles with server logins and database users

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've created in catalog \Security\Logins\ new login - ttt with password ttt. Then I've created user ttt with role db_datawriter.

To check whether user is admin(`db_owner`) or just user I call function `IS_MEMBER('db_owner')` in SQL MS(run using SQL authentication with login ttt and password ttt) and the result is 0.

When I call this function in C# the result is always true(or 1).

```
 Database obj = new Database(new Server(@"ADMIN-PC\MSSQLSERVER2"),"ShoppingMall");
 bool user = obj.IsMember("db_owner");
```

`Database` is a class from `microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo` 
Connection string is

```
  string connection_string = @"Data Source=ADMIN-PC\MSSQLSERVER2;InitialCatalog=ShoppingMall;User ID=ttt;Password=ttt";
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call the 'IsMember' method on the smo User object, not the Database object.

```
Database db = new Database(new Server(@"ADMIN-PC\MSSQLSERVER2"),"ShoppingMall");
User user = new User(db, "ttt");
bool isMember = user.IsMember("db_owner");
```